# Print or visually represent encrypted data

Tags: c#, .net, printing, visualization, barcode

I have a scenario that requires me to generate a printed page with encrypted data that can be scanned into our application later. Much like a barcode but encrypted.

The volume of text to be encrypted would be between 1KB to 10KB but could increase in the future. Most likely not above 1MB.

I develop document processing systems so I understand the dos and donts of printing. Scanning usually adds properties to printed pages such as skewing, rotation, artifacts, etc.

So the question is:

- What is the best format to represent this amount of data visually? Not barcodes I'm assuming.
- Whatever the format, real estate is crucial since we want to squeeze the data into a single A4 page. I'm thinking Base64 encoding with code-table compression could be a candidate? Any thoughts.

**EDIT**: It seems like barcodes are the only viable solution. The data is essentially a series of digits so I could use base 10 and then compress them to a code/index table before encrypting it. Or would using a higher base be wiser here?

Comment: Ask a specific programming question.

Comment: Alternatives to barcodes for visually encoding 10KB of data.

Comment: An A4 page can hold approximately 8.7 million bits of information, without margins, at 300 dpi. So in theory you could get a megabyte per page without compression. Give a 1/2 inch margin on all sides and you have about 7.8 million bits. That's about 955 kilobytes of information, assuming that your printer and scanner could work reliably at 300 dpi.

Comment: That's good insight @JimMischel but printing and scanning back unfortunately are not reliable at those resolutions.

Comment: Which was exactly my point. There's no way you're going to get even close to one megabyte on a single page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion would be to make a C# program that takes your data, encrypts it, then runs it through a Base64 encoder. Then I would take the Base64 data and create QR code bitmaps from the data. I would then shrink the bitmaps so you can fit a lot on a page, then I would print pages of those QR codes. Later you can scan them in, enlarge each code and then read in the data. Finally, you'd have to Base64 decode it and then decrypt it!

Comment: Thanks. Although most of the answers point in the same direction, I am selecting the earliest one to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

Is the application online?  If so, have you thought about storing the data securely (encrypted if you really want it that way) in a server, and on your page printing an access token (or simply a web reference) in the form of a [QR code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code)?  Upon scanning the token your app could then retrieve the actual data from the server.

**EDIT**
While the above would give you the higher reliability and scalability, you could still store the data in QR codes directly on the page.  You'd just need to encrypt into the alphanumeric space ([using Base64 encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7269464/55487)) and store it as a series of QR codes; [each can store around 3KB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3964312/55487), so you'd get a lot of data on the page (as long as the page wasn't damaged).

Comment: No, this solution is for a desktop app in offline mode. Barcodes would probably have to be the way out.

Answer (score 0):

[High-Capacity Color Barcodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Capacity_Color_Barcode) are 2D matrix codes that use colored "bars" (typically triangles) to encode data on printed pages. The Wikipedia article says they can store 3kB per square inch.

Obviously these require color printing and scanning hardware.

Comment: Hmmm... Yes that is a good option for certain scenarios but not when printing and scanning is involved, specially when you do not have control over the equipment.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to be able to run this completely offline from any internet or network access, I would suggest encrypting the text, hashing the encryption and storing the hash in a QR code. Getting a 2d bar or QR code to store a 64 or 128 bit hash should be easy enough, and reliable enough for scanning (as that's what they are designed for). Commercial QR scanners or software are available to make the scanning easy.

If you cannot have access to a common server between printing and scanning, then 2d barcodes are your only real option, and won't have the information density you want. You'd have a better chance storing it on RFID or a mini CD.